# Given a URL path, can I get the url params that would be used to fulfill the request?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, actiondispatch

For example in routes.rb I have something like

```
  namespace :api do
    namespace :v1 do
      post 'login/:email' => 'authentication#login', email: /[^\/]+/
    end
  end
```

Given the string `"/api/v1/login/lisa@example.com"` I would like to know that this path contains a param called `email` whose value is `lisa@example.com`

Comment: To clarify, this isn't just for email, a more general question. For example, 
`get 'foo/:id' => 'foo#show'`
Given the path `"/foo/123"`, I would like to know this path contains a parameter called `id` whose value is `123`

Answer (score 0):

You could use the following regex

```
/[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-.]+\.[a-z]+/
```

This would give you the result

```
"/api/v1/login/lisa@example.com".scan(/[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-.]+\.[a-z]+/).first

#=> "lisa@example.com"
```